# How to attach a DataGridview to an Outlook Email as an Attachment

Tags: vb.net

How can you add a an DataGridView as an email attachment. When the user selects send within the vb.net program it's suppose to attach the DataGridView to the email automatically. Can someone provide me with the steps to adding an email attachment in vb.net?

Thanks,
Tom

Comment: Attachments are files.  A DataGridView is not a file.  What do you want?

Comment: I would like to add a DataGridView to an email. When the user clicks on the email button I would want the DataGridView to be attached to the email. How can I write that code for vb.net? thanks

Comment: Perhaps convert the gridview to a html table. Easy to add html doc as a mail attachment.

Comment: That doesn't make any sense.  What kind of file do you want?

Comment: I just want the DataGridView to be added to the email. I'm having troubles trying to add it to the email.

Comment: That's like trying to attach an apple to an email.  _Your question makes no sense_.

Comment: No worries.. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Hi @Tom , what they are saying is .. you cannot attach directly the datagrid as an email attachment, because datagrid is not a file, what you need is to convert that datagrid into a file type.. such as getting all data in datagrid then put in in excel, so that you can attach the excel file in email.. or make it the datagridview to html .. that requires some html coding skills.. you need first to think on how your program will work, you cannot attach that datagrid directly.. as simple as that.

Comment: @Japongskie Thanks for the clarification. I was able to figure out the solution to my problem.